# Recovering Ubuntu - need help

Tags: boot, data-recovery, windows-10, boot-repair

Several weeks ago I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10. Yesterday when starting my laptop I saw:

```
error: unknown filesystem.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

I booted from USB stick and did grub repair as written in this manual:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Boot-Repair Boot Info Summary: http://paste.ubuntu.com/26476661/

After repairing grub, I rebooted my PC and no options for choosing the OS were given, but Windows automatically started and did a long update!
Rebooting again, only Windows was starting (even if I hold the left Shift key).
Booting from USB and typing in the terminal `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.4 GiB, 1532116992 bytes, 2992416 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sda: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd189d189

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       206848 208879660 208672813  99.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       208881664 209922047   1040384   508M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda3       209922048 381544007 171621960  81.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       381544446 625137663 243593218 116.2G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       517124096 625137663 108013568  51.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 3.8 GiB, 4026531840 bytes, 7864320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0389dc44

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 7864319 7862272  3.8G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

I can't remember in which partition Ubuntu was installed sda4 or sda5, but anyway as I understand it Ubuntu is gone?

This is output after running `sudo blkid` (if it helps).

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="0066D36A66D35F4A" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="d189d189-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="22DE2630DE25FCA3" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="d189d189-02"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="New Volume" UUID="022C50F22C50E1E9" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="d189d189-03"
/dev/sda5: LABEL="New Volume" UUID="7ED64136D640F047" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="d189d189-05"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="UBUNTU 16_0" UUID="622A-896A" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="0389dc44-01"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
```

Can someone please help me to recover my files, that were on Ubuntu (mainly .pdf books and some python scripts .py)?

Comment: Based on your boot info summary, it looks to me like you created a "bootable" live system on a VFAT partition at /dev/sdb1 (i.e. treated the partition as though it were a USB stick). Don't know how you would boot back into that though - sorry (it *may* be as simple as selecting /dev/sdb2 as the boot device from BIOS).